# Select() between netlink and unix socket fd

Tags: c++, ipc

I know select can be used to monitor different file descriptors. I would like to know whether select() can be used between AF_UNIX and netlink sockets to monitor them?

Appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried and an explanation of how the behavior that you see differs from what expected.

Comment: On Unix, `select` can accept any file descriptors including pipes or sockets of any type. That would not be true on Windows. But please show some code for a more detailed answer...

Comment: @SergeBallesta AFAIK, netlink sockets imply Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a socket e.g. with

```
int listfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

The result is a file descriptor, following the "everything is a file" philosophy. You can then call `select` on anything which is represented by a file descriptor.

It may be good to read about alternatives to `select`, [`poll` and `epoll`](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/06/03/async-io-on-linux--select--poll--and-epoll/). They can be more effiecient, and IMHO the interface is better because it does not use `FD_SET` etc.

If you have sufficient design freedom I would stay away from the network primitives and use a library or framework which handles the communication. I like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org), but there a many other choices. Implementing efficient and reliable communication seems easy at first, but it certainly has some difficulties which when you want to handle error cases, e.g. broken connections. These problems have been solved before.